# Sublime text syntax coloring quote issue

Tags: sublimetext3, react-native, sublime-text-plugin

I'm using sublime text 3 to code some react native stuff and when writing in text components I use quotes that mess up all the syntax coloring as in the picture below. Is there any way to fix this ?

[image: syntax highlighting messing up]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## React JSX syntax

`JSX` is the [JavaScript Syntax extension](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html) you normally use in your render method.

## Correct Color Scheme

Since `JSX` is an extension to the plain JavaScript, Sublime doesn't know about it. You have to tell Sublime to use the extension [babel-sublime](https://github.com/babel/babel-sublime).

### Installation of [babel-sublime](https://github.com/babel/babel-sublime)

Just follow the [official documentation](https://github.com/babel/babel-sublime/blob/master/README.md#setting-as-the-default-syntax) to install this plugin. I don't write it down, in case something changes in the future.
Also check the documentation about [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/installation), which you use to manage your Sublime Packages.

Comment: Please expand this answer to explain what the babel plugin is and why it would be useful in this circumstance. Link-only answers become useless if the link changes or is unavailable. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) for more. Just to be clear, I think this is the correct solution to the problem, you just need to explain more *why* this is the correct solution.

Comment: Sorry. Not so easy on mobile. Give me a second! :)